# Under which Visual Studio 2010 menu does the WSP Builder sub-menu appear?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint

I recently installed WSP Builder on a machine with Visual Studio 2008 already installed.
Quite expectedly, the WSP Builder sub-menu appeared (and still appears) under the Visual Studio 2008 Tools menu.

Having then installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional and installed WSP Builder a second time, I can not seem to find the WSP Builder sub-menu anywhere under any of the Visual Studio 2010 menus.

Can anyone throw some light on this "missing menu" problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 already supports SharePoint 2010 out of the box. WSP Builder is a Visual Studio 2008 tool, and there's no need for it in 2010 anymore - as long as you target SharePoint 2010. If you target SharePoint 2007, you should probably stay with VS2008.

Answer (score 3):

I am in the same situation as you using VS2010 to target SP2007 since we haven't upgraded to SP2010 yet.  Some of the new VS2010 features are too nice to miss out on.

The WSPBuilder menu *should* appear under the Tools menu in VS2010.

Check under Tools > Add-in Manager to see if VS2010 is even aware that it is installed. It may be that it will show up in here in Add-in Manager and not be enabled which you can fix by checking the checkbox next to WSPBuilder in the Available Add-ins list.

If it doesn't show up here or you may need to uninstall the WSPBuilder Extensions from your Control Panel and try re-installing the latest version again.  I am using the "WSPBuilder Extensions 2010 BETA 1.4" from here http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/releases/view/30858